Using getvar to obtain MSLP from a wrfout file gives an error
Just a quick question. I'm trying to extract 850 hPa U and V winds along with MSLP from my wrfout file. Here's my current code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from wrf import getvar, interplevel, latlon_coords, ALL_TIMES

fileName = "wrfout1_d01_2024-11-14_12_00_00_5-day_fcst_rain"

wrf_file = Dataset(fileName)

# Extract the p, u, v, and mslp
p = getvar(wrf_file, "pressure", ALL_TIMES)
ua = getvar(wrf_file, "ua", ALL_TIMES, units="kt")
va = getvar(wrf_file, "va", ALL_TIMES, units="kt")
slp = getvar(wrf_file, "slp", ALL_TIMES, units="hPa")

# Interpolate u and v winds to 850 hPa
u_850 = interplevel(ua, p, 850)
v_850 = interplevel(va, p, 850)

# Get the lat/lon coordinates
lats, lons = latlon_coords(u_850)

The slp line gives me the KeyError: 'QVAPOR'
Any ideas?
